# Implement game center, and "missed method" error

Tags: iphone, ios, game-center

I'm trying to implement Game Center in my app.

I used [this tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-game-center-achievements-and-leaderboards-part-2/)

In my view controller I have :

```
- (IBAction) submitScore
{
    if(self.currentScore > 0)
    {
        [_gameCenterManager reportScore: self.currentScore forCategory: self.currentLeaderBoard];
    }
}
```

In GameCenterManager.m I have :

```
- (void) reportScore: (int64_t) score forCategory: (NSString*) category 
        {
            GKScore *scoreReporter = [[[GKScore alloc] initWithCategory:category] autorelease]; 
            scoreReporter.value = score;
            [scoreReporter reportScoreWithCompletionHandler: ^(NSError *error) 
             {
                     MyLog(@"scoreReporter %@", scoreReporter);
                 [self callDelegateOnMainThread: @selector(scoreReported:) withArg: NULL error: error];
             }];
        }

- (void) callDelegateOnMainThread: (SEL) selector withArg: (id) arg error: (NSError*) err
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void)
        {
           [self callDelegate: selector withArg: arg error: err];
        });
    }

- (void) callDelegate: (SEL) selector withArg: (id) arg error: (NSError*) err
{
    MyLog(@"selector %@", selector);
    MyLog(@"delegate %@", delegate);

    assert([NSThread isMainThread]);
    if([delegate respondsToSelector: selector])
    {
        if(arg != NULL)
        {
            [delegate performSelector: selector withObject: arg withObject: err];
        }
        else
        {
            [delegate performSelector: selector withObject: err];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Missed Method");
    }
}}
```

In my logs I have always written "missed method". I arrived to reported the first score (ex : 35), but now, impossible to report a new score (ex : 100).

The NSlogs are :

```
2013-01-25 20:21:25.847 isam[37958:c07] -[GameCenterManager reportScore:forCategory:]_block_invoke_1 scoreReporter <GKScore: 0xb19a3f0>player:G:1677639845 rank:0 date:2013-01-25 19:21:25 +0000 value:50 formattedValue:(null) context:0x0
2013-01-25 20:21:25.847 isam[37958:c07] -[GameCenterManager callDelegate:withArg:error:] selector scoreReported:
2013-01-25 20:21:25.848 isam[37958:c07] -[GameCenterManager callDelegate:withArg:error:] delegate <GameViewController_iPhone: 0xb16d120>
2013-01-25 20:21:25.848 isam[37958:c07] Missed Method
```

I think I read all the subjects on google about my issue but I don't arrive to find a correct solution.

Comment: This is glue code. It doesn't show us the actual problem you're having, and your explanation isn't clear.

Comment: Like @JonathanGrynspan is saying, the error is somewhere else. How about you set a breakpoint at `NSLog`, find out who was calling, then check if the selector's target is implemented.

Comment: I added code in my question for more explanations

Comment: I agree with @s.bandara. Does `delegate` exist? Is it the object you think it is? Does it respond to the selector in question?

Comment: Could you do two things to finally resolve this: (a) show us the full signature of `scoreReported`, (b) in `callDelegate` test if `delegate` is `nil`?

Comment: I added the logs for the selector, delegate and the scoreReporter